# my loop is wrong somehow,by using Y/N options in while loop

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    char counter='Y';
    int howmuch;
    counter=0;
    howmuch=100;

    while (counter=='Y')
    {
        int menu;
        float price;
        float totalprice=0.00;
        printf("please select from menu:");
        scanf ("%i", &menu);

        switch(menu)
        {
        case  1: {
            printf("one hotbox1 =RM10.50");
            totalprice=totalprice+10.50;

            break;
            }
        case   2:{ 
            printf ("one hotbox2=RM10.60");
            totalprice=totalprice+10.60;

            break;
            }

        case   3:{
            printf ("one hotbox3=RM10.70");
            totalprice=totalprice+10.70;

            break;
            }

        }
        printf("add order?(Y/N):");
        scanf ("%c", &counter);
    }
}
```

when I used counter increment such counter++ I can run it properly,but when I use Y/N(I'm not good ad that) the program is not doing its job.Can anyone explain this?My friends did not know about this too,and I've tried searching in forums regarding,got no clue

Comment: A good start would be to properly indent the code. I've seen more than a few bugs that are really hard to spot in unformatted code, but really easy to spot in formatted code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop doesn't get chance to execute, because while condition is false:

```
counter = 0;
howmuch = 100;
while (counter == 'Y'){
  // loop code 
  // unreachable code  
}
```

counter is `0` that is not `'Y'`.

Compile your code with -Wall option you may get a warning unreachable code.

Some additional side notes: learn about [indentation](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~mccann/indent_c.html), return type of main function should be int, check [syntax of main function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function#C_and_C.2B.2B).

Comment: Yeah you are right there,and I fixed it thanks,but then the loop is broken and I can only use it once.Thanks for the help,I appreciate it.EDIT:Thank @grijesh,I made it now,appreciate your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you comment out counter=0; then loop will work for only one time. that is because counter is of type char, and after

```
printf("please select from menu:");
scanf ("%i", &menu);
```

the stdin buffer is filled with the menu (options selected like 1 2 or 3) and a newline character (when you press enter key).

for the next scanf, that newline character will be considered as the input for counter.

you can try printing the counter value as "%d" outside the while loop in the above code, then cross check that with ASCII table.

To correct your code and you just add fflush(stdin); after scanf ("%i", &menu); like below

```
printf("please select from menu:");
scanf ("%i", &menu);
fflush(stdin);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int counter=0;
int howmuch=100;
while (counter < howmuch)
    //do something
    counter++;
{
```